# Autoencoder based on 3D CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, 3d-convolution

I am implementing a 3D CNN based autoencoder.

I want to fix the error

```
conv3D_encoder = keras.models.Sequential([
 keras.layers.Conv3D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3,3,3), padding = "same", input_shape=[8, 160, 160, 3], activation='relu'),
 keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size = (2,2,2)),
 keras.layers.Conv3D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3,3), padding = "same", activation='relu'),
 keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size = (2,2,2)),
 keras.layers.Conv3D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3,3), padding = "same", activation='relu'),
 keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size = (2,2,2))])

conv3D_decoder = keras.models.Sequential([ 
 keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=2, padding="valid", activation="relu", input_shape=[None,3,3,64]), 
 keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters = 16, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu"), 
 keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters = 1, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=2, padding="same", activation="sigmoid"), ])

conv3D_ae = keras.models.Sequential([conv3D_encoder,conv3D_decoder])

conv3D_ae.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.5))
history = conv3D_ae.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_valid,X_valid))
```

error Message:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None, 3, 3, 64) for input Tensor("conv3d_transpose_63_input:0", shape=(None, None, 3, 3, 64), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 20, 20, 64).

ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 12, 164, 164, 1) vs (None, 8, 160, 160, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The input of the encoder and the output of the decoder should be the same in an autoencoder. The input of the decoder will be the output of the encoder. Changing the architecture of the decoder will help.

```
conv3D_decoder = keras.models.Sequential([ 
 keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=2, padding="valid", activation="relu", input_shape=[1, 20, 20, 64]), 
 keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters = 16, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu"), 
 keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters = 16, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=2, padding="same", activation="sigmoid"), 
 keras.layers.Conv3D(filters = 3, kernel_size = (5,5,5), padding = "valid", activation='relu'),])
```

Please go through this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/98bdaa45b2bfc5e1d0a332223448268c/untitled99.ipynb#scrollTo=PvRfksmxAe6O), where I was able to replicate the error with random data.